# How to create runtime/dynamic trigger or job scheduler in spring framework integrate with database?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I just wanted to create n number of trigger/job scheduler by user. (ie) user wants to create job scheduler for sending their own reports to their email periodically.

The application should allow to create n number of scheduling time for every user.

For the reason,How to create job scheduler at run time by using spring with database and give me an idea or link to resolve it.

My application has developed with Java, Spring, Hibernate, MySQL

Comment: Are you looking for a Java-EE or Spring solution?

Comment: Hi i am looking for spring based solution. I wanted to store the scheduler time in database. guide me if you know solution

Answer (score 0):

Configure Quartz to use the database for storing the jobs:
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX

Scheduling a job (Quartz cookbook):
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/ScheduleJob

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://atrigger.com for scheduling your web app independent of the programming language(It's using REST API) and your server time, and more benefits such as error handling and task listing.

There are lots of feature to support multiple tasks for multiple users:
http://atrigger.com/docs/wiki/18/use-case-scheduled-welcome-emails

**Disclaimer**: I was among the ATrigger team. It's a freeware and I have not any commercial purpose.